# Weak equivalence of ordinary and homotopy colimits

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am looking for conditions under which colimits and homotopy colimits of diagrams of, say, topological spaces, are weakly equivalent. I would appreciate answers not demanding an all too profound background in model categories!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all spaces in consideration are compactly generated, a basic example is the one of a sequence $...\rightarrow A_i\rightarrow A_{i+1}\rightarrow...$ of closed inclusions.

The canonical map $$\operatorname{hocolim}(A_i)\rightarrow \operatorname{colim}(A_i)$$ is a weak equivalence, since the ordinary colimit commutes with taking homotopy groups in this case. (This is a Lemma on page 67 of May's book.)